# Bones don't attach to some parts of the body

Tags: rigging, bones

Disclaimer: I'm fairly new to Blender and 3d modeling in general.
I made a human-like structure with separate objects, then I joined them together and added bones. But when I rotate the bones, some parts of the body stay still.

I'm attaching a pic and the file.
I'll appreciate any help.

https://we.tl/t-dPfvhjdjGy

[image: The arms and legs are made by spheres and cylinders, but only spheres move]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how you've parented, but for this kind of object (non-organical, manufactured object) you should parent *With Empty Groups*. It will allow to precisely parent each piece to the vertex group it should be part of. Once done, go in *Edit* mode, select a part with <kbd>L</kbd>, open the *Object Data panel > Vertex Groups*, choose the vertex group the selected mesh should be part of and click on *Assign*.

Also you have inner faces in the body, probably because at one point you forgot to enable the *Clipping* option of the *Mirror* modifier, remove them.

Comment: You, sir or madam, are a life saver <3

Comment: you're welcome  ;)